# Plot certain columns of a data frame

Tags: r, graph, plot

My data frame has the following structure named dat:

```
  No.  Action  Title          Replies  PlusOnes  Reshares  Url                    
   1    Share   SomeTitle     2        3         1         http://plus.google.com 
   2    Post    AnotherTitle  3        4         5         http://plus.google.com
```

Here is the `dput(dat)` of my data:

```
structure(list(No. = 1:2, Action = c("Share", "Post"), Title = c("Some Title", 
"Another Title"), Replies = 2:3, PlusOnes = 3:4, Reshares = c(1L, 
5L), Url = c("http://plus.google.com", "http://plus.google.com"
)), .Names = c("No.", "Action", "Title", "Replies", "PlusOnes", 
"Reshares", "Url"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
))
```

How can I plot the columns `Replies`, `PlusOnes` and `Reshares` in a graph?
The x axis should be the `No.`, the y axis the number of Replies/PlusOnes/Reshares, and these columns should each have a separate line in the graph.

Regards

Comment: I see that you did an effort to format your data but it is better to keep it as it (just copy and paste) or better to show a dput ( see my edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this two ways:  using standard R graphics or ggplot2 (which I prefer).

Since the other answer explains how to do it with `matplot`, I'll show you another way to get a pretty-looking graph.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
dat<-data.frame('No.'=1:2,replies=2:3,PlusOnes=3:4,Reshares=c(1,5))
melted=melt(dat,id.vars='No.')

ggplot(melted,aes(x=factor(No.),y=value,color=factor(variable),group=factor(variable)))+
geom_line()+xlab('No.')+guides(color=guide_legend("Series"))+
labs(title="Insert Title Here")
```

Essentially what happens is that the `melt()` function from the reshape2 package will create a new row entry for each possible column value of each level of `No.`  It also stores the variable name of the value corresponding to it in each row, so it's easy to plot things like it with ggplot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
with(dat,matplot(x=No.,y=cbind(Replies,PlusOnes,Reshares),type="l")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `lattice` ( I edited to add the third variable)

```
xyplot(Replies+Reshares+PlusOnes~factor(No.),
       data=dat,type='l',auto.key=T)
```

[image]